# Rails - Multiple Models with root sluggable routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I'm looking for advice to find the ideal solution that fits within Rails' best practises.

My app has 5 models:

- Category
- Place
- Division
- Subdivision
- Item (polymorphic)

A Place belongs to a Category. A Division belongs to a Place. A Subdivision belongs to a Division, and an Item can belong to a Place, Division OR Subdivision.

Here is my routes.rb

```
resources :categories, path: ''

get ':category/:place', to: 'places#show', as: :place
get ':category/:place/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :place_item
get ':category/:place/:division', to: 'divisions#show', as: :division
get ':category/:place/:division/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :division_item
get ':category/:place/:division/:subdivision', to: 'subdivisions#show', as: :subdivision
get ':category/:place/:division/:subdivision/:item', to: 'items#show', as: :subdivision_item
```

The issue is that if I type in the URL:

```
/category/place/divison
```

The error is "could not find ITEM".

I am currently using friendly_id for the slugs, is there a best method for introducing a new model "Slug" that would handle the slugs for all 5 of these models?

Potentially something like this? (Haven't tested)

```
get '/*category_id', :controller => 'slugs'
```

Here's item_controller:

```
def show
end

def show_place_item
  render "show"
end

def show_division_item
  render "show"
end

def show_subdivision_item
  render "show"
end

private
    def set_item
      @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :slug, :category_id)
    end
```

Comment: How are you trying to find the item? Show some controller code.

Comment: Have added controller code for the item controller, pretty out-of-the-box at this point, mostly keen on understanding the potential of creating a Slug model to handle all routes for the 5 current Models.